# Alternate row and column every x post using modulo

Tags: php, bootstrap-4, row, multiple-columns, modulo

I am trying to implement alternate row and column every x post using modulo. And as the following example is displaying structure. The all posts are displaying but not as per the 2 and 3 posts structure. It looks like counter is not working and issue with modulo. Thanks for reviewing.

for example:

```
 // start for each     
 // 2 posts
        <div class="row">
         <div class= "col-md-6"></div>
         <div class= "col-md-6"></div>
        </div>

    // next 3 posts in different row 
    <div class="row">
      <div class= "col-md-4"></div>
      <div class= "col-md-4"></div>
      <div class= "col-md-4"></div>
    </div>

    // repeat this structure for all my posts so: 
    // 2 posts in a row 
    // 3 posts in a row
    // 2 posts in a row 
    // 3 posts in a row 
    // ... 
    // ...

-- end foreach --
```

Here's my code.

```
  <div class="wrapper container"> 
      <?php
       $count = 0;

     foreach(code) {
      if(!empty($listing_image_url)){     

        if ( $count % 5 === 0) : ?>
          <div class="row"> 
             <div class="col-md-6 list-column-block">
                  <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="<?php echo url($Url); ?>" class="listing__block__image">    
                  <div class="inner">
                    <?php if(!empty($listing_image_url)){ ?>                              
                      <img src="<?php echo $listing_image_url; ?>"/> 
                        <?php } ?>  
                          <div class="caption">
                            <div class="caption-inner">
                              <span class="caption-appeared">
                                <h5><span><?php print $Count; ?> homes</span></h5>
                              </span>
                              <span class="caption-des">
                                <?php print $title; ?></span><!--
                                 --><?php if ( $region ): ?><!--
                                 -->,<span class="caption-location">
                                      <?php print $region; ?>
                                      </span>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                    </a>              
                 </li>
               </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <?php endif;
            $count++; 
        if ($count % 5 === 1) :
          endif; 

        if ( $count % 5 === 2) : ?>
          <div class="row"> 
              <div class="col-md-4 list-column-block">
                    <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="<?php echo url($Url); ?>" class="listing__block__image">    
                  <div class="inner">
                    <?php if(!empty($listing_image_url)){ ?>                              
                      <img src="<?php echo $listing_image_url; ?>"/> 
                        <?php } ?>  
                          <div class="caption">
                            <div class="caption-inner">
                              <span class="caption-appeared">
                                <h5><span><?php print $Count; ?> homes</span></h5>
                              </span>
                              <span class="caption-des">
                                <?php print $title; ?></span><!--
                                 --><?php if ( $region ): ?><!--
                                 -->,<span class="caption-location">
                                      <?php print $region; ?>
                                      </span>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                    </a>              
                 </li>
               </ul>
             </div>
            </div>
          <?php endif;

            if ($count % 5 === 2 || $count % 5 === 3 || $count % 5 === 4) :
             endif; ?> 


       <?php } } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i can see, your code will produce a new row (with a single column) on each iteration.

To create the structure you want, you could use a temporary counter. I'll give you an quick working example (reduced to the essential). As you can see i use the modulo operator only to determinate if we have a odd or even row.

I hope this helps.

```
    $posts      = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
    $count_rows = 1;
    $tmp_counter    = 1;
    $html           = "";

    foreach ($posts as $post) 
    {
        if ($tmp_counter == 1){
            $html .= '<div class="row">';   // create a new row on first run and after counter resets 
        }

        if ( $count_rows % 2 === 1) 
        {   
            // even row >> 2 Cols
            $html .= '<div class= "col-md-6">'.$post.'</div>';  // I would recommend to use a function to generate the post markup

            if ($tmp_counter == 2)
            {
                $html .= '</div>';  // close the row 
                $tmp_counter = 0;   // reset the temporary counter 
                $count_rows ++; // increase number of rows
            }
        }
        else
        {   
            // odd row >> 3 Cols
            $html .= '<div class= "col-md-4">'.$post.'</div>';  // I would recommend to use a function to generate the post markup

            if ($tmp_counter == 3)
            {
                $html .= '</div>';  // close the row 
                $tmp_counter = 0;   // reset the temporary counter 
                $count_rows ++; // increase number of rows
            }
        }

        $tmp_counter++;
    }
    if ($tmp_counter != 1){
        $html .= '</div>';  // close the last row
    }
    echo $html;
```

Comment: Great! The logic is working and that's what I wanted. Thank you so much.

Comment: col-md-4 and col-md-6 have different height. What should I do set same row height for different column?

Comment: The height depends on your content. Why not use css rules to limit the height. You can give your content a fixed height and limit the text to a certain number of lines for example or make the text scrollable. 
This depends on your needs.